# Deciphering status in manuscript handling systems

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, canonical-question

We keep getting questions in which we are asked to decipher the status messages in some online submission management system ([latest one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/101412/guest-editor-in-chief-decision)).

I find it slightly annoying that we have to do the job of Elsevier's or Springer's customer support, and compensate for the poor UI of these systems.

It seems to me that the answer is almost always one of:

- check the [typical journal workflow](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like) and make your best guess;
- chill out and stop checking the status every day; you'll get an e-mail when it's over and there is no real way to speed it up (with a link to the other canonical question on [handling times](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/88355/));
- we really don't know; have you tried sending them an e-mail?

Should these questions be welcome on this site? Is it time for a canonical one? Should we close them all as "strongly depends on individual factors"?

Comment: The "typical journal workflow" question *is* the canonical one for that kind of Q.

Comment: What would you want to handle with a canonical question that is not and cannot be addressed by the existing canonical Q&As?

Comment: @ff524What about "ask your supervisor/advisor, that is the reason you have supervisor"?